# Checkbox.Group of ant design React couldn't set the default value

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks, antd

I am developing an ant-design based react functional application. While using the Checkbox.Group, I found that I can't set the default value on a dynamically generated list of select boxes. My criteria is, when the custom modal is opened, depending on the loginId(an integer value) passed, the checkbox should be selected by default. If I unselect then it's fine. But on opening modal for the first time, default value should be set. I'm really trying for a long time, don't know what exactly I'm missing. Would be great if you please help.

here is my code,

```
export const ContactModal = props => {
const loggedInUser = props.loginUserDetail.id > 0 ? [props.loginUserDetail.id] : [];

console.log("loggedInUser= ",loggedInUser);


const title =
    props.contactType === contactTypesEnum[1] ? 'Select MMS contact person' : 'Select Industry contact person';

return (
    <Modal
        title={title}
        visible={props.isVisible}
        width={'60%'}
        afterClose={props.modalClose}
        onCancel={props.handleContactModalCancel}
        footer={[
            <Button key="back" onClick={props.handleContactModalCancel}>
                Cancel
            </Button>,
            <Button key="submit" type="primary" onClick={props.contactModalConfirm}>
                {/*<Button key="submit" type="primary" onClick={props.inputSubmit}>*/}
                Submit
            </Button>
        ]}
    >
        {/*<Form key={props.contactList}>*/}
        <Form>
           <div style={{ overflowY: 'scroll' }}>
                
               
               {/*<Checkbox.Group defaultValue={[defaultValue]} onChange={props.handleCheckedInput}>*/}
                    <Checkbox.Group defaultValue={loggedInUser} onChange={props.handleCheckedInput}>
                    <Row style={{ border: '1px solid #009FE3', paddingLeft: '10px' }}>
                        {props.contactList.map((elem: { fullName: string; id: number }, index: number) => {
                            return (
                                <Col key={index} span={8}>
                                    <Form.Item> 
                                        <Checkbox value={elem.id}>{elem.fullName}</Checkbox>
                                    </Form.Item>
                                </Col>
                            );
                        })}
                    </Row>
                </Checkbox.Group>
            </div>
        </Form>
    </Modal>
);
```

};

The props.loginUserDetail, I'm passing looks like,

```
export interface ContactLogin {
id:number;
fullName:string;
```

}

and I checked very correctly that the id is getting populated and has non-zero positive value. Strangely if I hardcode `defaultValue={[12]}`  the right checkbox is marked but the variable assignment of `defaultValue={[loggedInUser]}`

In the ant design specification I found that the defaultValue type should be string so I tried to use,

```
const loggedInUser = props.loginUserDetail.id > 0 ? props.loginUserDetail.id.toString() : '';
```

But it is also not working. If variable value is not selectable then defaultValue={[12]}  shouldn't work too. BUt hard-coding is working.

THis is how I'm calling the custom modal,

this is how I'm calling the modal ,

```
<ContactModal
            isVisible={modalVisibilty}
            //modalClose={modalClose}
            contactList={contactList} //this would be number of contact returned
            handleContactModalCancel={handleContactModalCancel}
            contactModalConfirm={contactModalConfirm}
            handleCheckedInput={handleCheckedInput}
            //contactListError={contactListError}
            contactType={contactType}
            loginUserId={contactType === contactTypesEnum[2]?loginUserDetail.id:0}
            //loginUserDetail={contactType === contactTypesEnum[2] ?loginUserDetail : {id:0,fullName:''}}

        />
```

Can anyone please help me out here ? Thanks much !

Comment: can i know how many times your console.log("loggedInUser= ") is printing and what are the values?

Comment: @Hemanthvrm : It's like this from my console.log , loggedInUser=   

loggedInUser=  
fetchContacts : contactType = techie
contactType =  techie
loggedInUser=  
fetched data = (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
loggedInUser=  
loggedInUser=  
retunred login =  {id: 12, fullName: "Jonas Andrew"}
loggedInUser=  12
loggedInUser=  12
loggedInUser=                       CreateNew.tsx is my maincode from which the above custom modal is called where I passed the login data. the last loggedInUser=  happens when I close the modal

Comment: , –  ?? i mean whats you said id is correctly populating.. what is the console.log("loggedInUser= ",loggedInUser);  result in your browser... is it printing multiple times with different values? or just 12

Comment: currently I'm just testing with 1 user . so it is always 12. I mean in my modal there are multiple checkbox but for defaultvalue I am just passing always for now 12

Comment: default value is what it gets assigned only for first time.. if for first time loggedInUser is some emptyvalue for any other reason(like data needs to be fetched from api)... after passing emptyvalue loggedinUser to defaultValue for first time will be final and the next time it wont get changed, even the props got changed... thats the reason i am confirming whether it is printing in console anyother value other than 12

Comment: @Hemanthvrm : but will it load the defaultvalue every time I load the modal then if I make check whether the value is non-empty while loading the modal ? Also, do I need to generate the "key" for each checkbox. Here for example, I generated it at column level.

Comment: @Hemanthvrm : How can I then make my checkbox auto checked during modal load ? I thought default value is the option . I saw at checkbox level there is defaultchecked but that is also not working. I think the reason is same.

Comment: col level key is also fine...I am not sure how antd is loading modal i have to reconfirm their code(i guess it is mounting but hiding until visible prop is true).. give this a try  {props.isVisible ?  <Modal visible={true}>your checkbox code here </Modal>: null}

Comment: this way i am sure that modal is unmounting and mounting as well as value that got assigned to defaultvalue updates everytime modal got mounted with the value that you passed

Comment: Since we dont have your requirement and also your parent component is not available i am unable to provide a better answer... One other approach is write a useeffect with loggedInUser dependency... inside useeffect change the checkbox value using props.handleCheckedInput ...Now you can remove default value and just use value prop with your checkbox state value

Comment: @Hemanthvrm:I added some more detail about how I'm calling the modal . But thanks much that you tried to help.

Comment: i will frame code and will post the two approaches as answer soon, give it a try ..... before that i would like to confirm can u hardcode the value const loggedInUser = ["12"] on top instead at defaultValue prop directly, so that we can make sure that the problem is correct as we discussed

Comment: @Hemanthvrm: yes with hardcoding it is working fine always.

Comment: I have same trouble, dynamic data not work to change defaultValue in Checkbox.Group. So, I must reload page when onOk or onCancel

Comment: I've fix it, I use value not defaultValue, and use onChange to set state for value.
<Checkbox.Group
            name="name"
            className="list_checked_provider"
            options={[
              'A', 'B'
            ]}
            value={checked}
            onChange={onChangeCheckbox}
          />